# Question about principal bundle on Wikipedia

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_bundle#Examples) it is stated that

> These fibers can be glued together in a natural way so as to obtain a
>   principal $GL(n,R)$-bundle over $M$.

I don't understand what they mean by glued together. Aren't the fibers glued already because each is attached to the base space $M$?

Comment: I think an alternative is to say that "These fibers can be *collected* together ..." The idea is that the union of the fibers is the total space of the fiber bundle. That is, to speak of the notion of "fiber bundle", you must have a total space (obtained by collecting the fibers together). The base space is already given to you but you need to define the total space as well.

Comment: Then there is no gluing going on there?

Comment: Well, there's another criterion in the definition of a fiber bundle. Locally, the fiber bundle should look like a product. If you glue your fibers together arbitrarily, then there's a chance that this criterion won't be satisfied. So, you need to be a little careful. Of course, when I say "glue", what I'm really talking about is the topology on the total space. After all, it's this topology that specifies exactly how the fibers are glued together. (The total space of a fiber bundle is the union of all the fibers; so, as a set, it's not very interesting. It's the topology that's interesting.)

Comment: Concretely, think about your favorite fiber bundles over the circle: the cylinder and the Mobius band. The fiber for both of these fiber bundles is a line but the fibers are glued together differently in each case. In the case of the Mobius band, they are glued together so as to create an "overall twist". In the case of the cylinder, no such twist exists. Locally, both fiber bundles are the same; the fibers are locally glued together so as to resemble a product. But globally this isn't the case for the Mobius band ...

Comment: ... Also, think about manifolds. Locally, they're Euclidean; globally they can be more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector bundle is trivialized by/on some cover of your manifold, and of course there are transition maps when you represent the "same" vector that is sitting on top of two different particular open sets, which of course we know. This is what they mean by gluing (of the original vector bundle). Then, the same transition maps "naturally" induce a gluing of the associated principle bundle (instead of thinking of the data vector by vector, we get transition maps by taking a "matrix of bases" to another matrix of bases.)